# Access Email Recipients in a HTML Email?

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to send out an email to a list of recipients loaded from MYSQL database from a desktop application. I want to include a link at the end of the email which allows people to remove themselves from the email list: `http://www.mysite.com/removeemail.php?email=______`. The problem is that the email has multiple recipients. Is it possible to send an email which would adjust the value passed to the php script through the email parameter? The alternative would be to send each person an individual email with the link, which is viable, but more time consuming.

I assume that this isn't possible, but I figured that it couldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Either create the email body from within PHP or create a template email that you can replace a given string in. We need to see your code to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, it isn't possible. You will need to send 1 email per recipient with an identifying token in the unsubscribe link.

This is one of the reasons lots of sites contract their mailing lists to another company. Managing a large volume of email and subscribe/unsubscribe functionality becomes time consuming.